# Getting column number by vector value - R

Tags: r, matrix, match, multiple-columns

I have been stuck with this issue for some time now, without finding any help online.

I have two vectors of 1.314.000 entries, one indicating wind speeds and one indicating wind directions (values are 1-12 as the direction is consolidated into 12 directions).
I also have a matrix of 50001 rows and 13 columns, indicating power production of a turbine at a given wind speed (column 1) and wind direction (column 2-13)

Calculating the power production seemed obvious:

```
PowerkWh <- PCC[ws*1000+1,1+wd]
```

PCC is the 50001x13 matrix and ws and wd is the wind speed and wind direction variables. Note that i do not use match as it resulted in NA's for some reason.

Head of ws, wd and PCC:

ws:

```
[1]  2.327 16.971  3.469 23.558  7.882 10.619
```

wd:

```
[1]  5 10 10  9  1  1
```

PCC:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
[1,] 0.000    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     
[2,] 0.001    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     
[3,] 0.002    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     
[4,] 0.003    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     
[5,] 0.004    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     
[6,] 0.005    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
```

Note that PCC is 0 since wind turbines are usually only turned on when wind speeds are above 3.5 m/s

This code works fine to get the correct row (setting a constant column/direction, say 5), however my issue is getting the appropriate column, given the wind direction in wd. R simply outputs that its memory has been reached since in interprets it as a 1.314.000x1.314.000 matrix - I'm expecting a 1.314.000 vector with the production from the given wind speed and wind direction.

Hope you are able to see what I dont, as I dont want to resort to using loops due to time consumption - let me know if you need anymore information :)

Thanks!

Comment: can you dput the head of your two vectors and the matrix?

Comment: I almost want to suggest building a statistical model from the 50001 x 13 matrix --- that thing is essentially a lookup table for the measurements you have (the two vectors of length ~1.3 million each). However, it might just be more direct to make use of `approxfun`. I'll see if I can work something up.

Comment: surely, head is now included - thanks

Comment: @Sophus, thanks. Just a question, are you sure the wind speeds on your big vectors are all in the first column of your matrix?

Comment: Oh yes, the first column contains wind speeds rounded to 3 decimals, that are supposed to be matched with the wind speeds found in ws, whereas columns 2:13 are power production at those wind speeds, given one of the 12 directions given in wd.

Comment: @rbatt I'm also trying to use approx to extrapolate the power production linearly (also allowing for more than 3 decimals) like so:
    approx(PC[,1],PC[,wd+1],xout = ws)$y
However R still interprets the PC[,wd+1] as being a matrix of ~1.3mill columns, and therefore outputs that x and y lengths differ

Comment: @SophusBonnenRossen See my answer -- the might help. You should give `approxfun` a try like in my answer; `approx` could be made to work, so I did it that way for stylistic reasons. Just note that you'll run into problems if the first column of `PCC` doesn't cover the full range of values in `ws`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer assumes that the same units for wind speed in `ws` are the units in the first column of `PCC`.

```
# ===============================
# = Quick Options for Fake Data =
# ===============================
n.dir <- 12 # number of wind directions
n.sample <- 50 # number of samples in the vectors

# ================================
# = Create Fake Data for Example =
# ================================
# create fake vectors and lookup tables
ws <- rlnorm(n.sample) # wind speeds
wd <- sample(1:n.dir, n.sample, replace=T) # wind directions
PCC <- matrix( # empty lookup table for power
    data=NA, 
    nrow=length(unique(ceiling(ws)))+1,
    ncol=length(wd)+1
)
# note the +1 is so that the top row of PCC
# references values that are closest to 0;
# i.e., the starting row of the lookup matrix
# references the lowest possible wind speed

# generate fake power values; 
# absolute values to make realistic
# data are also sorted so that more wind is more power
# beyond that, it is not realistic
dataExprsn <- expression(sort(abs(rnorm(nrow(PCC)))))
PCC[] <- replicate(ncol(PCC), eval(dataExprsn))
PCC[,1] <- c(0,sort(unique(ceiling(ws))))

# =============================
# = Approach to be Used by OP =
# =============================
power <- rep(NA, length=length(ws)) # to store output
for(i in 1:n.dir){ # do it by direction to save time
    t.index <- wd==i
    t.fun <- approxfun(x=PCC[,1], y=PCC[,i+1])
    power[t.index] <- t.fun(ws[t.index])

}

# ==============
# = The Answer =
# ==============
power
```

Comment: I just updated this answer because the first version did use the information that the first column contained actual wind speeds (I got confused at first)

Comment: That got the job done, and also uses to approxfun! thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try - if the first columns of `PCC` contains all element of `ws`:

```
PCC[cbind(which(PCC[,1] %in% ws), wd + 1)]
```

Comment: this is problematic if there isn't an exact match

Comment: Works if there is rounded wind speeds, rbatt's solution did the trick without. Thanks though :)

Comment: this is better (faster, less code) than my answer if there are exact matches.